# C# adding referenes at run time

Tags: c#

Sorry if it is a duplicate post.
[link text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/629414/adding-references)

but i didnt get any clear solution..

my application loads various dll, and processes them. so i need to add the dlls in my references list at run-time.

how can i add an assembly(dll) as reference in a C# project at run time.?! i need to add a reference at run time.!? i.e normally we add references by **Right-Clicking  References in Solution Explorer** and we can browse for any dll and add it in references.  i need to do this using code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Reflection;
namespace GetType_success
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Assembly a = Assembly.LoadFrom(@"C:\Documents and Settings\E454935\My Documents\Visual Studio 2005\Projects\nunit_dll_hutt\for_hutt_proj\bin\Debug\for_hutt_proj.dll");            
            Type t = Type.GetType("for_hutt_proj.Class1,for_hutt_proj");             

        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code of the Class library for_hutt_proj
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Text;

```
namespace for_hutt_proj
{
    public class Class1
    {


            public int add(int a, int b)
            {
                int c = 0;
                c = a + b;
                return c;

            }
}
}
```

where, the dll has just an add method returing int.
if i add this dll manually in RightClicking and adding references in Solution explorer, 't' has proper type. else it has null.
but i need to add this dll as reference to my project at run time i.e using code and not through UI. how can i do this at run time.?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Suggest you close this as a duplicate...

Comment: Clarity of answer is usually a function of clarity of question. If you can't get the right answer to start with, clarify the existing question instead of asking it yet again.

Comment: Are you both Arunachalam *and* pragadheesh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got the solution. 
if i use, the below code its working fine.

Type type = asm.GetType("for_hutt_proj.class1", false, true);

credits to Marc Gravell.